# Link not pointing to next element while adding

Tags: c, linked-list

This is a simple program to add elements at the end of the Linklist using C.

```
void main() {
    int i, n, x;
    struct Node* Head = NULL;
    struct Node* temp1;
    printf("Enter the no. of elements:");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    printf("\nEnter the elements:");
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        temp1 = Head;
        struct Node* temp = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
        scanf("%d", &x);
        temp->data = x;
        temp->next = NULL;
        if (Head != NULL) {
            while (temp1 != NULL) // This part is not working properly
            temp1 = temp1->next;
            temp1->next=temp;
        } else {
            Head = temp;
        }
    }
    temp1 = Head;
    while (temp != NULL) {
        printf("temp=%d tempdata=%d \n",temp,temp->data);
        temp = temp->next;
    }
}
```

The while part is not linking the new elements with the previous elements.

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: `temp1` is null right after `while(temp1!=NULL)`, so calling `temp1->next` right after will likely crash your program.

Comment: Related,  if you're going to chain elements to the end of a list being built, a pointer-to-pointer will make much of that code, and particularly the head-check, obsolete. This technique for building is sometimes called *forward chaining* , and including the error checking your code is missing, it looks [something like this](https://ideone.com/Q2GI04). Best of luck.

Comment: The first problem is the first line of the posted code.  Even in a 'bear bones' system, the first item to run is `start.s` So there is always some place to return to.  Note: there are only two valid signatures for `main()`  `int main( void )` and `int main( int argc, char *argv[] )`  Notice that all the valid signatures (irregardless of what some compilers allow) all have a `int` return type

Comment: The second problem is the needed `#include` statements for the needed header files are missing`.  Are you expecting us to guess as to what header files your code actually used?

Comment: The third problem is : `temp1 = Head;
    while (temp != NULL) {`  Where the pointer `temp1` is set, but the `while()` loop is using `temp`.   `temp1` and `temp` are not the same

Comment: OT: regarding: `struct Node* temp = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));`  1) the returned type is `void*` which can be assigned to any pointer.  Casting just clutters the code, making it more difficult to understand, debug, etc  2) always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  If not successful, call `perror( "my error message" );` to output both your error message and the text reason the system thinks the error occurred to `stderr`

Comment: OT:  regarding: `scanf("%d",&n);` and similar statements: always check the returned value (not the parameter values) to assure the operation was successful. (any returned value other than the number of `input format conversion specifiers` indicates an error occurred.)  Suggest: `if( scanf("%d",&n) != 1) { fprintf( stderr, "scanf for ... failed\n" ); }` such an error is usually followed by 'cleaning up' and calling `exit( EXIT_FAILURE );`

Comment: The posted code is missing the definition of `struct Node`.

Comment: Please post a [mcve] so we can reproduce the problem and help you debug it.

Comment: when building the linked list: regarding: `temp1 = temp1->next;
            temp1->next=temp;`  the code needs to remember the address of the just visited node, so the pointer: `temp` can be assigned.  OTHERWISE when the assignment is made, the value in `temp1 is already NULL, resulting in trying to write something to address 0.  An excellent way to cause a seg fault event  Suggest replacing: `while (temp1 != NULL)`  with `while( temp1->next )`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing

```
while(temp1!=NULL)
    temp1=temp1->next;
```

to

```
while(temp1!=NULL && temp1->next != null)
    temp1=temp1->next;
```

should fix this ;)

Comment: Angevil but for printing it is working to iterate till the end element. Then why do I need to add &&here

Comment: because without the && temp1->next != null you won't stop before reaching null pointer, which is not what you want :) you wanna stop one before the null pointer.

Comment: But while printing too we iterate till we get null. But there we only go for temp!=NULL. There we dont check for temp->next!=NULL

Comment: 1 --> 2 --> 3 --> null

After a loop with (temp!=null) -> your pointers points to null (great if you want to print them all, but you have no access to last element anymore)

After a loop with (temp != null && temp->next != null)  -> your pointer points to 3, which is what you want when adding a new element to the end, as you want to access 3--> next to set your newly created element (say 4).

Comment: do{
 printf("\nEnter the no. to be added and the position(Total elements= %d):",m-1);
 scanf("%d%d",&x,&n);
 insert(x,n);
 printf("Do you want to insert more elements Y/N?");
 scanf("%c",&opt);
}while(opt!='N'&&opt!='n');

Comment: whats wrong with this do-while loop it wait until I enter a char. It just prints the 'Y/N' statement and goes on iterating to accept only x and n

Answer (score 1):

As @Groo pointed out, temp1 is null at the end of the while loop so you cannot call temp1->next.

So Just replace the line with

```
 while(temp1->next!=NULL)
```

But you don't have to traverse all the list elements every time you do an insert to the linked list. As the temp1 would be pointing to the last element in every iteration you just have to make it next pointer to point to the newly allocated node. As done in the below code.

```
 #include<stdlib.h>
 #include<stdio.h>
 struct Node{
        int data;
        struct Node *next;
 };
 void main(){
    int i,n,x;
    struct Node* Head=NULL;
    struct Node* temp1;

    printf("Enter the no. of elements:");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    printf("\nEnter the elements:");

    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
            struct Node* temp=(struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
            scanf("%d",&x);
            temp->data=x;
            temp->next=NULL;
            if(Head!=NULL){
                    temp1->next=temp;
                    temp1 = temp;
            }
            else {
                    Head=temp;
                    temp1 = Head;
            }
    }
    temp1=Head;
    while(temp1!=NULL){
            printf("temp=%d tempdata=%d \n",temp1,temp1->data);
            temp1=temp1->next;
    }
```

}